# Laravel Store Method Error

Tags: laravel, controller

hey Guys i am using resources route for posts i have store method in my PostsCOntroller controller that i created.

my form is

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<form method='POST' action='PostsController@store'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Text Area</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

whenever i clikc submit i get this error

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message

> Stacktrace:
>
> #26 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:255
>
> #25 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:methodNotAllowed in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:242
>
> #24 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:getRouteForMethods in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:176
>
> #23 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:599
>
> #22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:578
>
> #21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:564
>
> #20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
>
> #19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}
>   in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
>
> #18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:56
>
> #17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>
> #16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>
> #15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
>
> #14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>
> #13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>
> #12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:30
>
> #11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>
> #10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>
> #9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
>
> #8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>
> #7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>
> #6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
>
> #5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle
>   in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:149
>
> #4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
>
> #3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:102
>
> #2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
>
> #1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
>
> #0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php:55

Comment: Have you declared a post route in your routes.php/web.php depending on your laravel version?

Comment: yeah i have actually Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Comment: how about trying the url form of form then? eg: {!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts']) !!} Don't forget to close the form with {!! Form::close() !!}

Comment: i did not wanted to do that. i tried url form and it works but i wanted to make it work without the url version.

Comment: ok, then can you try Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store'']) ? Same as above, close the Form after finishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action is wrong. You should use url not action or controller name. Try this:

```
<form method='POST' action='{{route('posts.store')}}'>
```

`route` helper generates url by route name. In your case it will return `http://yourdomain/posts`

Comment: According to your comment this `Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController')` should define this route. But it looks like it doesn't. Try  `php artisan route:list` in console and you will see all defined routes with urls and names

Comment: try this `<form method='POST' action='{{url('posts')}}'>`

Comment: it gave no error now buy says The page has expired due to inactivity after i press submit button but yes it is redirecting to correct url now.

Answer (score 0):

1. define your route at file web.php

   Route::post('posts', 'PostsController@store')->name('posts.store');
2. update your view template to